# The stream was not openned for reading

Tags: c#, .net, caching, memorycache

I am downloading a PowerPoint file from Cloud. To restrict the multiple call for downloading the file, I am caching it using `MemoryCache`. The below code runs fine for first run, but after the first run it throws an exception:

> "The stream was not opened for reading."

Below is the code I am using:

```
var cache = MemoryCache.Default;
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
if(cache.contains(key)) {
    memoryStream = (MemoryStream)cache.Get(key);
} else {
    var file = getFile();
    cache.Add(key, file);
    memoryStream = (MemoryStream)cache.Get(key);
}

using(memoryStream) {
    Open file and do manupulation then save the file in cloud.
}
```

Updated code:

```
var cache = MemoryCache.Default;
byte[] data = (byte[])cache.Get(key);
if(data == null)
{
    data_stream = getData(); // get memorystream
    cache.Add(key, data_stream.ToArray(), new CacheItemPolicy());
    data = (byte[])cache.Get(key);
}

using(Stream outputStream = new MemoryStream(decktemplate)) {
    Open file and do manupulation then save the file in cloud.
}
```

still getting the following error: "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow."

Following is the stacktree:

```
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOExtraField.ParseRecord(BinaryReader reader, ZipIOZip64ExtraFieldUsage zip64extraFieldUsage, UInt16 expectedExtraFieldSize)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOCentralDirectoryFileHeader.ParseRecord(BinaryReader reader, Encoding encoding)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOCentralDirectoryBlock.ParseRecord(BinaryReader reader, Int64 centralDirectoryOffset, Int32 centralDirectoryCount, Int64 expectedCentralDirectorySize)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOCentralDirectoryBlock.SeekableLoad(ZipIOBlockManager blockManager)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOBlockManager.get_CentralDirectoryBlock()
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipArchive.GetFiles()
   at System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage.ContentTypeHelper..ctor(ZipArchive zipArchive, IgnoredItemHelper ignoredItemHelper)
   at System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage..ctor(Stream s, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Boolean streaming)
   at System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(Stream stream, FileMode packageMode, FileAccess packageAccess, Boolean streaming)
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.OpenCore(Stream stream, Boolean readWriteMode)
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.PresentationDocument.Open(Stream stream, Boolean isEditable, OpenSettings openSettings)
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.PresentationDocument.Open(Stream stream, Boolean isEditable)
```

Comment: Because it's in a `using` block, it gets disposed. Also, you probably need to rewind it after use (it's not a VHS but it does have an internal pointer to where it is). Also, will you always be caching in-memory (serializing a stream is conceptually hard)?

Answer (score 2):

Storing a `MemoryStream` as an *object* in cache is a very bad idea, because multiple threads could be accessing it concurrently. It is a much better idea to store the *payload*, as perhaps a `byte[]` or `ArraySegment<byte>`, and use that to create a *different* `MemoryStream` for each caller. Otherwise, you are going to be tripping over yourself constantly:

```cs
byte[] payload = (byte[])cache.Get(key);
if (payload is null)
{
    payload = GetFilePayload();
    cache.Add(key, payload);
}
using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(payload, writable: false))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: still I am getting the same error: "The stream was not openned for reading." When marking the writable as true for MemoryStream, it is giving an exception: "Arithmetic operation resulted in a overflow"

Comment: it doesn't sound like either of those is coming from the code shown; do you have stack traces?

Comment: @ManjurAnsari specifically, the first one sounds like incorrect file-handling code in your `getFile` method, and the second sounds like some incorrect data processing code in the "and do manupulation" code. You haven't shown us either of those.

Comment: getFile method is returning MemoryStream. Actually the file is .pptx. In the manipulation I am opening the .pptx file and extra slides to it and uploading the final deck to cloud.

Comment: @ManjurAnsari nothing in that statement makes me assume that the code is *correct*

Comment: I have added the stacktree in the question.

Comment: @ManjurAnsari great; but that stack trace has *very little* to do with the code shown in the question; we can't help you with code you don't show us

Comment: Gravel I got the issue. When we use byte[] payload = (byte[])cache.Get(key), the payload has reference to the cache object. Hence when we make any changes to the payload, it is reflected in the cache. Therefore in second run, the file is already written (in first run) that results in exception. What I did is copied the byte array and then processed.